# Know password, but can't SU or run commands with sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, sudo, root

This issue popped up about a week ago, not sure what caused it. Previously the environment had been working as expected. Using a VM hosted on VMWare tools, uname -a returns roughly the following.

```
-virtual-machine 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

For example, sudo su root returns

```
"Sorry, user linuxUser is not allowed to execute '/bin/su root' as root on linuxUser-virtual-machine."
```

sudo apt-get install vim

```
"Sorry, user linuxUser is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get install vim' as root on linuxUser-virtual-machine".
```

However I can execute commands as linuxUser, like ls -la or vim.

id returns the following

```
uid=1000(linuxUser) gid=1000(linuxUser) groups=1000(linuxUser),999(docker)
```

What I've tried

1. editing sudodoers, I can't modify the file because I don't have root access
2. Changing linuxUser's password, had no effect

I've googled around pretty heavily on this, but it seems like most users are either still able to execute sudo commands or are still able to switch to root. Any ideas?

sudo -l -U linuxUser returns the following

```
Matching Defaults entries for linuxUser on linuxUser-virtual-machine:
env_reset, mail_badpass,
secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin
User linuxUser may run the following commands on linuxUser-virtual-machine:
(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/checkAPT.py
```

POSTMORTEM EDIT: Hey All, I fixed the issue with https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user. Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you have taken yourself out of the sudo group by accident, you wont be able to use sudo.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have root authority on this system?

Comment: You should show the sudodoers file. Did you change something in that file?

Comment: @RalfFriedl, not sure how to view sudodoers without admin access. The file has not been modified since 2017.

Comment: @JeffSchaller how can I check if I have authority?

Comment: You said it yourself: `linuxUser is not allowed...` and `...because I don't have root access`

Comment: @All see edit on my post above

Comment: From our sister site: [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo ls`?

Comment: `sudo -l` as the user in question should show you what sudo privileges you have

Comment: Fixed it everyone, just had to add the user back to the sudo group. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> User linuxUser may run the following commands on linuxUser-virtual-machine:
> (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/checkAPT.py
> ```

Well, that rather plainly says that you're not authorized (as far as `sudo` is concerned) to run anything other than that script.

If you were allowed to run arbitrary commands, there would be a line in the output to that effect:

```
User thisuser may run the following commands on thishost:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (root) NOPASSWD: /some/other/utility
```

That access could be given by username, or by group membership.

```
someuser   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL          # by user
%sudo      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL          # by group
```

If the `/etc/sudoers` file has not been modified, then perhaps your membership in the `sudo` group has been removed (the group could have some other name, of course)?

There's no way to know, without seeing the configuration, which you can't see without sufficient access. Reinstall and restore from backups, or open the disk (image) in another system where you have enough access.

Comment: Quite the opposite, actually. `(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/checkAPT.py` indicates that the user is **allowed** to run that script with **no password**.  I don't see any indication that the user is allowed to run anything other than that.

Comment: @TimKennedy, added the missing negation to the first sentence... thanks.

Comment: Accepting this because it was the closest, the easy fix was to do https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user

Answer (score 0):

Try to mount the system disk (system disk file) to a reliable linux system where you have the *root* rights. Then you can investigate the `passwd`, `group`, `sudoers` and all other relevant files, and/or you can use `chroot` to enter into the failing system.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Sorry, user %s is not allowed to execute '%s%s%s' as %s%s%s on %s.` is a different error to `%s is not in the sudoers file`. (I have not read source, I just ran `strings` in the code in `/usr/lib/sudo/*`.)

Therefore you may still be in sudoers file. Someone may have reconfigured it.
Try various commands, you may find something that will help you. If not then you need to mount the disk on a different OS instance, and fix it.